# CMake debian package with only XML file (no executable or library)

Tags: cmake, debian

I want a simple thing: have CMake create a debian package with single XML file (no executables/libraries).

Unfortunately I cannot get it to work. I have tried to install the target like this:

```
set(TARGET_TEST_NAME "xml-util-package")
add_custom_target(
    ${TARGET_TEST_NAME} ALL)

install(TARGETS ${TARGET_TEST_NAME}
    COMPONENT ${TARGET_TEST_NAME}
    RUNTIME DESTINATION "/home/"
    DESTINATION "/home/"
)

install(FILES ${xml_configs} DESTINATION "/home/")
```

Error that I get is:

```
CMake Error at ... (install):
  install TARGETS given target "xml-util-package" which is not an executable,
  library, or module.
```